# Reload Class When Dependent Resource Changes in Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

You know how Eclipse reloads classes automatically running in Tomcat when resource files they depend on such as spring context files are updated so that you don't have to re-start Tomcat? How do I make a class dependent on a resource file so that Eclipse re-publishes it when the resource file changes? Eclipse would re-publish Spring classes when their dependent resource files are updated, but would not re-publish mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you want the class to be republished ? Do you mean that you want the contents of the bean in the application context to be updated ?  If that's the case, then what you can do is the following :

1) Write a file system monitor to monitor the resource(s) for changes.  There's an example [on google code](http://code.google.com/p/google-enterprise-connector-file-system/source/browse/trunk/projects/file-system-connector/source/java/com/google/enterprise/connector/filesystem/FileSystemMonitor.java?r=43)

2) Have that file system monitor fire a custom Spring ApplicationEvent whenever the file / resource changes, providing that event the information for the resource, if necessary.  ie the file name, the previous modified time, the last modified time, etc.

3) Have the bean you want to be updated implement ApplicationEventListener and reload the resource when it catches your file system monitor event.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if it's Spring that's doing this for you. Are you developing in an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans? What might be happening is as you make code changes your IDE is 'publishing' (i.e. re-deploying) your app code, so the app re-initializes every time the IDE publishes it, giving the illusion that Spring is reloading context files as they change.

This is useful with a small app but get's very annoying the larger your app gets.

If you're looking for this behavior for development, take a look at JRebel:
http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/

Comment: Yup. I'm using Eclipse. What I'm confused about is that Eclipse would re-publish Spring's core classes when their dependent resource files are updated, but would not re-publish my custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but working workaround can be to add an ant builder to your project. Steps to take:

1. read the article
       here
       http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm
2. create a simple ant file, that
   contain a target, which [touches](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html)
   (simply changes the date of
   modification) the dependent classes,
   but nothing else (if you need help in it, let me know). Eclipse will provide you variables inside the script. You can print them easily with  task. You will see the list in console.
3. right click on the project, and
   press properties
4. open "builders" tab in properties
5. add your ant script as a builder to
   the project
6. restrict the set of resources this
   ant builder is called for. This can
   be done in "build options" tab in ant
   builder options. This way your
   project will be fast, and the ant
   script will only run for the changes
   of the property file
7. set the set of resources (classes depending on properties) to refresh after running the ant script in "Refresh" tab
8. Set your ant script target to be called for "Auto build" in "target" tab. Others like after and before clean and manual build should be empty
9. You may redirect log of the ant script to file if you want. Otherwise it will open console view.
10. move your builder to be the first in the list of builders, since it must run before java builder

This is a workaround, and should work. It will have no bad side effect, since the content of java file will not change, and it will not affect the version control system, as well as the whole thing is workspace independent, if the ant script is in your project.