# Is there way to reload autowired instance or replace autowired behavior in spring

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Currently I have a bean that is created in @Configuration which downloads json documents from web and creates a model object. Using this bean (autowired), lot of other beans are initialized on startup

I need a way to reload the bean whenever the json documents changes in the web.

What is the best way to do it?

Code:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.wellmanage.prism")
public class PrismConfig {

...
@Bean
public Model model(@Qualifier("prismRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {

    LOG.info("model()");
    MetadataReader metadataReader = new MetadataReader();
    String prismFormatJson = null;
    if (!isHasLatestTransformedJson()) {
        prismFormatJson = metadataReader.transformToPrismJson(restTemplate, environment);
        setLastGoodPrismConfiguration(prismFormatJson);
    } else {
        prismFormatJson = getLastGoodPrismConfiguration();
    }
    if (model != null) {
        return model;
    } else {
        return metadataReader.createModelForPrism(prismFormatJson);
    }
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.wellmanage.prism")
public class PrismDataSourceConfig implements DataSourceConfig {

private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PrismDataSourceConfig.class);

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Autowired
private Model model;

@Primary
@Bean(name = "itdb_dataSource")
public DataSource getDataSource() {

    LOG.info("getDataSource()");
    return getDataSource("itdb");
}

@Bean(name = "dataSourceMap")
public Map<String, DataSource> getDataSourceMap() {

    LOG.info("getDataSourceMap()");

    Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    getDatabases().forEach((name, database) -> {
        Endpoint endpoint = getEndpoint(name);
        DataSource dataSource = createDataSource(endpoint);
        dataSourceMap.put(name, dataSource);
    });

    return dataSourceMap;
}

@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplateMap")
public Map<String, JdbcTemplate> getJdbcTemplateMap() {

    LOG.info("getDataSource()");

    Map<String, JdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateMap = Maps.newHashMap();
    getDataSourceMap().forEach((name, datasource) -> {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
        jdbcTemplateMap.put(name, jdbcTemplate);
    });

    return jdbcTemplateMap;
}

@Override
public Environment getEnvironment() {

    return environment;
}

@Override
public Model getModel() {

    return model;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with [ConfigurableApplicationContext.refresh()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh--)?

Comment: Will it not refresh the whole context? I want to refresh only the bean and its dependencies?

Comment: Yes, that would refresh the whole context. Trying to refresh just a part of it sounds like asking for trouble. I don't know your exact situation, but to me, it all sounds rather like design issue - I'd try to redesign so that the application context doesn't need to change when a remote resource changes.

Comment: One more thing to consider - it is possible to have "parent" and "child" contexts, with parent context's beans being available in the child context. That way you could separate the beans that do not need to change from the ones that do. Then you could refresh only the child context.

Comment: I have added the code snippet for your reference, i need to recreate model whenever the configuration changes externally and i dont have a parent /child context (not sure how to create that as this model and data sources are very widely used). If possible, i can change to factory bean based approach but not sure how to incorporate in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is very wrong. Autowiring is for connecting dependencies at startup. (It is actually discouraged these days, in favour of constructor argument injection.)

What you probably need is to have a `@Service` which retrieves the data model from the remote service. You then inject this service in the classes that need it to get the model.

You can then also use caching like EhCache and add an annotation `@Cacheable` to your method so that you don't get the model from the remote source everytime it is needed by the other classes. (You can configure your `ehcache.xml` for how long you want the cache to live before refreshing the data).

```
@Service
public class ModelService {

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public ModelService(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  @Cacheable(value = "model", key = "#root.methodName")
  public Model getModel() {

    MetadataReader metadataReader = new MetadataReader();
    String prismFormatJson = null;
    if (!isHasLatestTransformedJson()) {
        prismFormatJson = metadataReader.transformToPrismJson(restTemplate, environment);
        setLastGoodPrismConfiguration(prismFormatJson);
    } else {
        prismFormatJson = getLastGoodPrismConfiguration();
    }
    if (model != null) {
        return model;
    } else {
        return metadataReader.createModelForPrism(prismFormatJson);
    }
  }

  //... the rest of the code
}
```

Here we configure the cache to expire after 10 minutes:

```
<config
  xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
  xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
  xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
  http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

  <service>
    <jsr107:defaults>
      <jsr107:cache name="model" template="model-cache"/>
    </jsr107:defaults>
  </service>

  <cache-template name="model-cache">
    <expiry>
      <ttl unit="minutes">10</ttl>
    </expiry>
  </cache-template>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring is a concept for the application startup phase (or similar scopes like session and request). Even if you found a solution, you are  abusing spring concepts and asking for trouble.

So you should instead use Spring Events to update the contents of a single bean that does not change, same as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188343/2986984:

1) Write a class monitor to monitor the resource(s) for changes.

2) Have that file system monitor fire a custom Spring ApplicationEvent whenever the file / resource changes

3) Have the bean you want to be updated implement ApplicationEventListener and reload the resource when it catches your event.